# How to Disable All Custom and Core SpringSec Filters for a URL?

Tags: spring-security

Using Spring Security 3.0.5, I created a custom filter.

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>XAuthToken</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mckesson.security.filters.XAuthToken</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>XAuthToken</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Using the `filters = "none"`, I tried to disable **all** (Spring Security core & custom filters) using:

**spring-security.xml**

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/foo/bar" filters="none" />  
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/**"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" logout-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

However, when I accessed `http://localhost:8080/app/.../foo/bar`, a print statement shows up in my Tomcat log that indicates that my custom filter was run.

How can I disable all custom and core Spring Security filters?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are trying to do since you want a login, but don't want anything secured.  However, you can create a separate realm (you can have multiple `<http`> tags in a single configuration) and simply turn off security completely:

```
<http pattern="/unsecured/**" security="none"/>
```

Obviously the pattern can be whatever you want.
I'm not sure if that is exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Unfortunately my web-app's routes aren't broken up into `/unsecured` and `/secured`.

Comment: It turns out I'm only using the web.xml filter, not spring security